# Vrtra's "nameless body/secret place"

Tags: rig-veda, vritra

I've been reading up on the Rg Veda and find one verse peculiar.

> अति॑ष्ठन्तीनामनिवेश॒नानां॒ काष्ठा॑नां॒ मध्ये॒ निहि॑तं॒ शरी॑रम् । 
> **वृ॒त्रस्य॑ नि॒ण्यं** वि च॑र॒न्त्यापो॑ दी॒र्घं तम॒ आश॑य॒दिन्द्र॑शत्रुः ॥
>
> atiṣṭhantīnām aniveśanānāṃ kāṣṭhānām madhye nihitaṃ śarīram | 
> **vṛtrasya niṇyaṃ** vi caranty āpo dīrghaṃ tama āśayad indraśatruḥ ||

English translation:

> “The waters carry off the nameless body of Vṛtra, tossed into the midst of the never- stopping, never-resting currents. The foe of Indra has slept a long darkness.”

Doniger translation:

> "In the midst of the channels of the waters which never stood still or rested, the body was hidden. The waters flow over Vṛtra's secret place; he who found Indra an enemy to conquer him sank into long darkness"

What exactly does **"vṛtrasya niṇyaṃ"** refer to? Or am I reading the Sanskrit incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

This verse is part of first mandala, 32 sukta, [verse 10](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc829274.html). This Sukta talks about manly deeds of Indra and how he achieved, the "Thunder weilder" by killing a Asura by name "vṛtrasura". As said in first verse of same sukta:

> “I declare the former valorous deeds of Indra, which the thunderer has achieved; he clove the cloud; he cast the waters down (to earth); he broke (a way) for the torrents of the mountain.” ||1||

...

> “With his vast destroying thunderbolt, **Indra struck the darkling mutilated Vṛtra**; as the trunks of trees are felled by the axe, so lies Ahi prostrate on the earth.” ||5||

> “**The arrogant Vṛtra, as if unequaled, defied Indra, the mighty hero, the destroyer of many**, the scatterer of foes; he has not escaped the contact of the fate (Indra's) enemies. The foe of Indra has crushed the (banks of the) rivers.” ||6||

So, now it is clear Vṛtra was a Asura. Now What exactly does "vṛtrasya niṇyaṃ" refer to? To answer your question, we should read the verse correctly.

> atiṣṭhantīnām aniveśanānāṃ kāṣṭhānām madhye nihitaṃ **śarīram |**
> **vṛtrasya niṇyaṃ** vi caranty āpo dīrghaṃ tama āśayad indraśatruḥ ||

Where **shariram** means **body** which has to be connected to the next line **vṛtrasya niṇyaṃ**. vṛtrasya means "vṛtra's" and "niṇyaṃ" means hidden/secret. Simply saying "vṛtra's hidden" may not sound correct, but if we say "vṛtra's hidden body", it would make sense as after Indra kills him, the water flows over him and makes his body hidden.

I found more relatable translation from [sri-aurbindo's rigveda mandala 1, sukta 32](https://sri-aurobindo.in/workings/matherials/rigveda/01/01-032.htm):

> **The hidden body of Vritra**  laid in the midst of courses of the not standing ones, not stopping – the Waters  spread widely; {he,} to whom Indra is enemy, lay in the long darkness.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The mantras of Vedas are multi layered and have metaphoric meanings. Story of Vritra and Indra is used to describe the process of raining.

> The  deposited  body  was  in  the  midst  of  waters  which  neither
> stay  nor rest  Waters  march  against  the  secret  (outlet)  of
> Vrtra ;  in  deep  darkness lay  he  whose  enemy  is  Indra. The
> deposited  body,  i.e.  the  cloud,  was  in  the  midst  of  waters
> which neither  stay  nor  rest,  i.  e.  waters  which  are
> non-stationary. Sarira  (body) is  derived  from  (the  root)  ar  (to
> kill),  or  from  iam  (to  destroy).  **Waters march  against,  i.e.
> know,  [the  secret]  outlet of  Vrtra.**  Dirgha  (long)  is derived
> from  dragh  (to  lengthen).  Tamos  (darkness)  is  derived  from
> tan (to  spread).  A-iayad  is  formed  from  (the  root)  d-s%  (to
> lie).  Whose enemy  is  Indra,  i.  e.  Indra  is  his  slayer,  or
> destroyer,  therefore  he  (is called)  having  Indra  as  his  enemy.
> **'Rut  who  is  Vrtra?  ‘It  is  a  cloud,’ say  the  etymologists.**  [c
> It  is  a  demon,  son  of  Tvasta,’  say  the  legendarians.] The
> phenomenon  of  rain  is  produced  by  the  commingling  of  water
> (vapours) and  lightning  ( jyotis ).  With  reference  to  this,
> there  are  figurative descriptions  of  battle.  Indeed,  the
> descriptions  of  Vedic  stanzas  and the  narratives  of  the
> Br&hmanas  (depict  him),  r.o  doubt,  as  a  serpent. By  expanding
> his  body,  he  blocked  the  channels  (of  the  rivers).  When he
> was  killed,  waters  flowed  forth.  The  following  is  the  stanza
> which explains  this. **[Nirukta 2:17]**

So as we can read that Vritra is actually the cloud. The [commentry](https://archive.org/details/TheNighantuAndTheNirukta/page/30/mode/2up?view=theater) on the verse explains;

> **Durga  explains  ninyam  as  the  outlet  in  the cloud  through  which  the  waters  flow  down.** Roth  translates  Vrtraaya  ninyam  as  ‘non  Vrtra
> unbemerkt’,  i.  e.  without  being  noticed 'by Vrtra ;  see  op.  cit  p.  21.